# Add a bookmark in IE to all computers in network

Tags: windows-explorer, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9, windows-server-2008-r2

Can anyone please help shed some light on how I can add a bookmark in IE to all computers on a network remotely from the server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you meant IE Favourites, you can use Group Policy.

In the GPM, got to User Configuration > Windows Settings > Internet Explorer manager > URLs > Favourites and Links.  Add your Favourites.

Then apply the GPO to whichever computer groups you want to, using AD groups and/or WMI filters.

Answer (score 1):

Synchronizing is the way to go. Try this:

http://www.xmarks.com

The plugin lets you synchronize across multiple machines and multiple browsers. So if you add on one machine, it will add to all other 'clients' as well.